# REST list pagination

Tags: rest, paging, knockoutjs

I'm having a little bit trouble crating a list pagination.
I know that I can use next__ but I'm new to js and rest so I can't find a way.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
GetItemFromList();
Printitem() ;
});

var allItems = ko.observableArray([]);

function GetItemFromList() {
urlRest = "RESTURL/items?$orderby=Created desc&$top=2";
console.log(urlRest);

var self = this;
$.ajax({
    url: urlRest,
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function (data) {      
        var item = data.d;
        var next = data.d.__next ;
        console.log("next "+next);

        for (var i = 0; i < item.results.length ; i++) {

            var ID = item.results[i].ID; //Get item ID
            var type = item.results[i].type; //

            var firstNameUnit = item.results[i].Unit1;
            var secondNameUnit = item.results[i].Unit2;

            var Details = { 
            showtfirstName : firstNameUnit,
            showsecondName : secondNameUnit,

            }   
      allItems.push(Details);       
    },
    error: function (error) {
    }
});


}

function Printitem() {
var tr = document.getElementById('allItemsTable')
ko.applyBindings(self, tr);
}
```

My HTML is simple, a table with all the data and I'm using KO to bind the data.
I would like to have two buttons NEXT and PREVIOUS.
I've tried this [TUTORIAL](http://www.sharepointyammertech.com/2014/11/sharepoint-2013-how-to-implement.html) but I wrote my code before reading this (I have more calculations and items in the object but I deleted them because it's not relevant for the question).

thanks for the help!

Comment: In case you want to try with JSOM, refer this link. I used it once and it works perfectly -- https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-JSOM-list-5104ca92